# AOSP build system dumpvar not only on environment variables

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, cyanogenmod

I know that it's possible to print out a build variable (e.g. the `TARGET_DEVICE`) with

`CALLED_FROM_SETUP=true BUILD_SYSTEM=build/core make -f build/core/config.mk dumpvar-TARGET_DEVICE`

But how do I print a variable that gets set after the environment setup, therefore during the build system goes over all those Android.mk files, e.g. the variable `ALL_MODULES` or `PRODCUT_PACKAGES`.

What I've tried already:

`CALLED_FROM_SETUP=true BUILD_SYSTEM=build/core make -f build/core/config.mk dumpvar-ALL_MODULES`

`CALLED_FROM_SETUP=true make -f build/core/main.mk dumpvar-ALL_MODULES`

Both versions don't print anything (but do print something when I check for example `TARGET_DEVICE`).

So my actual question is how can I show the ALL_MODULES (or any other later set) variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding line

```
$(info ALL_MODULES=$(ALL_MODULES))
```

into your `Android.mk` file?

Comment: Hmm... If I put this into an `Android.mk` file, I only get the modules added before the file. Of course I could also put it into the `build/core/main.mk` file into the section after including all the subdir makefiles.
But is there a way without modifying/patching the buildsystem? (maybe possible to parse with a script too...)

Comment: _If I put this into an Android.mk file, I only get the modules added before the file._ but this variable is only set as result of **include**-ing the **Android.mk** files. You can put `$(info` in the last line of the last file that will be loaded by build.